# Zip a large file in Google Drive before downloading

Tags: google-drive, file-conversion

I've received a link to a large file (2 GB) in Google Drive. I know the file has a very high compression ratio, and my internet connection is really slow.

Is there any way to zip the file before downloading it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't zip single files, but if you download multiple files at once Google will zip all of the files.

Easiest option is to select your large file, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+Click on Mac) on a second file, and right click either file and select "Download". Google will then take an astronomical amount of time to process the two files and eventually let you download a zip of the two files.

[image: Multiple files selected with 'Download' context-menu option selected.]